# Regex: extract a number after a string that contains a number

Tags: r, regex

Suppose I have a string:

`str <- "England has 90 cases(1 discharged, 5 died); Scotland has 5 cases(2 discharged, 1 died)"`

How can I grab the number of discharged cases in England?

I have tried

`sub("(?i).*England has [\\d] cases(.*?(\\d+).*", "\\1", str),`

It's returning the original string. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `regmatches/gregexpr` to match one or more digits (`\\d+`) followed by a space, 'discharged' to extract the number of discharges

```
as.integer(regmatches(str, gregexpr("\\d+(?= discharged)", str, perl = TRUE))[[1]])
#[1] 1 2
```

If it is specific only to 'England', start with the 'England' followed by characters tat are not a `(` (`[^(]+`) and `(`, then capture the digits (`\\d+`) as a group, in the replacement specify the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
sub("England[^(]+\\((\\d+).*", "\\1", str)
#[1] "1"
```

Or if we go by the OP's option, the `(` should be escaped as it is a metacharacter to capture group (after the `cases`).  Also, `\\d+` can be placed outside the square brackets

```
sub("(?i)England has \\d+ cases\\((\\d+).*", "\\1", str)
#[1] "1"
```

Comment: If I have a string that's: str <- "England has 90 cases(discharged 1); Scotland has 5 cases(discharged 1)", i.e, discharged is in front of the number, how can I extract it? Thanks!

Comment: I would the regex lookaround  `as.integer(regmatches(str, gregexpr("(?<=discharged )\\d+", str, perl = TRUE))[[1]])#
[1] 1 1`

Comment: That's so helpful thank you! Could you please explain the difference between (?<=discharged) and (?= discharged)?

Comment: @Viveme679 `?<=` checking the match for digits succeeded by discharge and the `?=` after the digits

Answer (score 1):

We can use `str_match` to capture number before `"discharged"`.

```
stringr::str_match(str, "England.*?(\\d+) discharged")[, 2]
#[1] "1"
```

Answer (score 0):

the regex is \d+(?= discharged) and get the first match